# Yii framework CGridView in 3rd. party application

Tags: php, yii

I'm trying to implement CGridView in my website which only uses Yii framework without creating Yii application.

So here is the content of index.php:

```
require_once(dirname(__FILE__).'/../framework/yii.php');
$dbConf = array(
        'components'=>array(
                'db'=>array(
                        'connectionString' => 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=yii_tour',
                        'emulatePrepare' => true,
                        'username' => 'root',
                        'password' => 'root',
                        'charset' => 'utf8',
                ),
        )
);
Yii::createWebApplication($dbConf);
Yii::import('zii.widgets.grid.*');

$message = new Message();
$dataProvider = new CActiveDataProvider($message);

$grid = new CGridView();
$grid->dataProvider = $dataProvider;
$grid->run();
```

This code works without any errors. The only problem is that it only outputs "Total 10 result(s)." and that's it. I can't see the grid.

I checked in html and this is what I got:

```
<div>
        <div class="summary">Total 10 result(s).</div>
        <table class="items">
                <thead>
                        <tr>
                        </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                        <tr class="odd"></tr>
                        <tr class="even"></tr>
                        <tr class="odd"></tr>
                        <tr class="even"></tr>
                        <tr class="odd"></tr>
                        <tr class="even"></tr>
                        <tr class="odd"></tr>
                        <tr class="even"></tr>
                        <tr class="odd"></tr>
                        <tr class="even"></tr>
                </tbody>
        </table>
        <div class="keys" style="display:none" title="/democms/grid.php"><span>1</span><span>2</span><span>3</span><span>4</span><span>5</span><span>6</span><span>7</span><span>8</span><span>9</span><span>10</span></div>
</div>
```

I guess I'm missing something important here. Please help!

Comment: why not use Bootstrap from twitter instead if you just want the UI widgets

Comment: is Message class derived from CActiveRecord?

Comment: @bool.dev Yes. I have generated this class using gii.

Comment: @Orlymee This is not the case where I just want some widgets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to init columns for grid by

```
$grid = new CGridView();
$grid->dataProvider = $dataProvider;
$grid->init();
$grid->run();
```